# How to determine if record exist in tableview in javafx

Tags: javafx, tableview

I have a table view that I add row manually and I want to know before to add a row if that record that will be add it is already in the table.

Comment: Just do `if (tableView.getItems().contains(...))`. Make sure your model class defines `equals(...)` appropriately.

Comment: Can you show me a example??

Comment: @James_D Can you show me a example???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

James_D is saying that you have to add `@Override public boolean equals(Object obj)` method in your class. This will allow you to use default List `contains()` function so you can just do something like this in your controller code

```
if(!table.getItems().contains(newObj))
   table.getItems().add(newObj);
```

Here is example code:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        ObservableList<MyObject> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                new MyObject("Robert"),
                new MyObject("Nick"),
                new MyObject("John"),
                new MyObject("Kate"));

        TableView<MyObject> table = new TableView<>();
        table.setItems(items);
        TableColumn<MyObject, String> column = new TableColumn<>("Column Name");
        column.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));
        table.getColumns().addAll(column);
        table.setItems(items);

        TextField textField = new TextField();
        Button button = new Button("Add");
        button.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
            MyObject newObj = new MyObject(textField.getText());
            if(!table.getItems().contains(newObj)){
                table.getItems().addAll(newObj);
            }
        });

        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.getChildren().addAll(table, textField, button);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 475));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static class MyObject {
        private String name;

        public MyObject(String name) {
            setName(name);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            return obj instanceof MyObject &&
                    ((MyObject) obj).name.equals(name);
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
```

And it will be a propper way to go, but if you can't change objects class you can always use this or similar helper function.

```
  public static boolean contains(TableView<MyObject> table, MyObject obj){
        for(MyObject item: table.getItems())
            if (item.getName().equals(obj.getName()))
                return true;

        return false;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @varren. The helper function worked for me :)

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
Boolean checkItemAdded = table.getitems().stream().anyMatch(itemCheck->itemName.equals(itemCheck.getItem)));
//ItemName can be a string from a component like a ListView. Then:
If(!CheckItemAdded) { table.getItems().addAll(); }
Else
{
    //enter code here
}
```